# Fetching Data using RTK-query Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I setup my Redux like this

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:6969/api/coins';
const createRequest = (url) => ({ url });

export const coinApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'coinApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getCoins: builder.query({
      query: () => createRequest(`/watchlist`),
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetCoinsQuery } = coinApi;

import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { coinApi } from '../../src/services/coinApi';
import { setupListeners } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query';

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [coinApi.reducerPath]: coinApi.reducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(coinApi.middleware),
});

setupListeners(store.dispatch);
```

and in my component I am rendering the data in JSX by this

```
const CoinList = () => {
const { data, isFetching } = useGetCoinsQuery();
console.log(data);
```

When I `console.log(data`) it shows me the correct data however when I map in JSX, it gives me a type error of: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`

Am I suppose to give data a Typescript of if it exists?
Why is data undefined when the `console.log` is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Ah. I just figured out then I must add

```
if (isFetching) return 'Loading ...'
```

or else data is still undefined since its not fetched yet? Not sure but this was the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize data = [ ]
const {data = [ ] ,isFetching} = useGetCoinsQuery()

check this https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/rtk-query

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).